# Using Bootstrap and react, how exactly can I get these features I am looking for?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, components, dropdown, styling

[image: Screenshot of what I am trying to accomplish]

Hello everyone, I am a bit confused as to how I can get the functionality below on my website. Essentially, I need a drop down, that shows the sub sections of the drop down. The sub section must be clickable, and there must be a tick to mark it as complete. For example, if I clicked purpose of charity, it would bring me to a text field.

I would really appreciate any help on what exact components I could use to accomplish this. I decided to learn react so I am very new to it.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not 100% clear, so I'm gonna assume you want some Dropdown Menus of which the items have CheckBoxes to indicate their value. Since you are using Bootstrap, I will post an example using the React-Bootstrap library, which has ready Bootstrap components for React.

First, you are going to have some sort of state to save all the selected values:

```
state = {
    purposeOfCharity: false,
    privateBenefit: true,
    achievableYearPlan: true,
    resourcesAvailable: false
}
```

When you have a state, or any other source of information (since you are a beginner, stick with a class-component's state), you can render a checked/unchecked CheckBox accordingly.

This is the link for the React-Bootstrap library: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Here is the code for each drop down:

```
<Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle>
        Advancing Charitable Purpose
    </Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item>
            <Fragment>
                <Form.Check type="checkbox" checked={this.state.purposeOfCharity}
                    onClick={() => this.setState({purposeOfCharity: !this.state.purposeOfCharity})
                />
                <span>Purpose of Charity</span>
            </Fragment>
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item>
            <Fragment>
                <Form.Check type="checkbox" checked={this.state.privateBenefit}
                    onClick={() => this.setState({privateBenefit: !this.state.privateBenefit})
                />
                <span>Private Benefit</span>
            </Fragment>
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item>
            <Fragment>
                <Form.Check type="checkbox" checked={this.state.achievableYearPlan}
                    onClick={() => this.setState({achievableYearPlan: !this.state.achievableYearPlan})
                />
                <span>Achievable Year Plan</span>
            </Fragment>
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item>
            <Fragment>
                <Form.Check type="checkbox" checked={this.state.resourcesAvailable}
                    onClick={() => this.setState({resourcesAvailable: !this.state.resourcesAvailable})
                />
                <span>Resources Available</span>
            </Fragment>
        </Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

In case `Form.Check` is not working, try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.resourcesAvailable}
    onClick={() => this.setState({resourcesAvailable: !this.state.resourcesAvailable})
/>
```

Of course, you can do the same thing with plain HTML components and set the according bootstrap `className`s to your components. The span inside each `Dropdown.Item` has to be given a Bootstrap `className` if you want the text to have a specific style. Bootstrap does not have any `Typography` components, like [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) and other libraries do.